# attribute needs changing from string to real

Tags: string, attributes, weka

I have a csv file with two attributes: 1 real and 2 nominal
When I try to load the csv file into weka attribute 1 ends up as a string

I have tried formatting the attribute 1 column in excel as a number but nothing changes...I still end up with a string

What should I do ?

Bob M

Comment: Can you update your question with a snippet of the CSV file and the generated ARFF header? It is possible that your CSV file either used double quotes around the numeric values or had a non-numeric value in the column, leading Weka to believe that this is not a numeric column after all.

Comment: finding it difficult to add a snippet of code

Comment: have found the problem.....erroneous entries in that column